# String format printing with python3: How to print from array?

Tags: python, python-3.x, printing, string-formatting

Python3 has the super string.format printing:

```
'{} {}'.format('one', 'two')
```

If my strings are in an array, one way would be to type them out:

```
a = ['one','two']
'{} {}'.format(a[0],a[1])
```

But how can I print from an array, instead of having to type out each element?

For example, broken code:

```
a = ['one','two']
'{} {}'.format(a)
```

Gives me an expected error: `IndexError: tuple index out of range`

Of course, playing with `','.join(a)` won't help, because it gives one string rather than 2.

(Or is there a way to do this better with f-strings?)

---

And for full-disclosure, I'm using a raw-string because it has some geometrical significance, and my real code looks like this:

```
hex_string = r'''
            _____
           /     \
          /       \
    ,----(    {}    )----.
   /      \       /      \
  /   {}    \_____/   {}    \
  \        /     \        /
   \      /       \      /
    )----(    {}    )----(
   /      \       /      \
  /        \_____/        \
  \   {}    /     \   {}    /
   \      /       \      /
    `----(    {}    )----'
          \       /
           \_____/
'''

letters = list('1234567')

print(hex_string.format(letters[0], letters[1], letters[2], letters[3], letters[4], letters[5], letters[6]))
```

Comment: if anyone is curious, it's for an open source python port of the New York Times' puzzle game "Spelling Bee": https://github.com/philshem/open-spelling-bee

Comment: I'm not sure any of the usual string formatting schemes will help here since you need the output of each formatted item to leave the surrounding data untouched.

Comment: @quamrana yes, I had to add one space character each time I used `{}` because the brackets are replaced by one character

Comment: Your example above uses `'one'` and `'two'`. What about when `'three'` turns up?

Comment: yes, and actually, my question isn't specific enough, because I always want `letters[0]` in the center hexagon, which is the 4th `{}`

Comment: You may need to organise this problem into a series of questions you can ask on this site.

Comment: yes, good idea. thanks! https://stackoverflow.com/q/56092622/2327328

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [unpacking](https://medium.com/understand-the-python/understanding-the-asterisk-of-python-8b9daaa4a558) to expand the array during the function call.

```
print(hex_string.format(*letters))
```

Output:

```
            _____
           /     \
          /       \
    ,----(    1    )----.
   /      \       /      \
  /   2    \_____/   3    \
  \        /     \        /
   \      /       \      /
    )----(    4    )----(
   /      \       /      \
  /        \_____/        \
  \   5    /     \   6    /
   \      /       \      /
    `----(    7    )----'
          \       /
           \_____/
```

Answer (score 2):

Try unpacking the elements of the list using `*` as following. For example, printing would look like

```
print ('{} {}'.format(*a))
# one two
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `*` notation for lists:

```
print(hex_string.format(*letters))
```