# String format printing with python3: print from unpacked array *some* of the time

Tags: python, python-3.x, printing, string-formatting, python-3.7

In my [question a few minutes ago](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56092475/2327328), I asked about how to print using python's `str.format` printing, when the strings are stored in an array.

Then answer was clearly unpack the list, like this:

```
# note that I had to play with the whitespace because the {} text is 2 characters, while its replacement is always one

hex_string = r'''
            _____
           /     \
          /       \
    ,----(    {}    )----.
   /      \       /      \
  /   {}    \_____/   {}    \
  \        /     \        /
   \      /       \      /
    )----(    {}    )----(
   /      \       /      \
  /        \_____/        \
  \   {}    /     \   {}    /
   \      /       \      /
    `----(    {}    )----'
          \       /
           \_____/
'''

letters = list('1234567')

print(hex_string.format(*letters))
```

But if I always want the center hexagon to have printed inside the first item in the array: `letters[0]`, how can I mix unpacking the array with keeping the 4th printed string from the first array element?

I'm open to other printing types, like f-strings.

For example:

```
print(hex_string.format(letters[3], letters[1], letters[2], letters[0], letters[4], letters[5], letters[6]))
```

So that my output actually looks like this:

```
            _____
           /     \
          /       \
    ,----(    4    )----.
   /      \       /      \
  /   2    \_____/   3    \
  \        /     \        /
   \      /       \      /
    )----(    1    )----(
   /      \       /      \
  /        \_____/        \
  \   5    /     \   6    /
   \      /       \      /
    `----(    7    )----'
          \       /
           \_____/
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try something like this with `.format()`:

```py
a = '123'
print('{2}, {0}, {1}'.format(*a))
```

which would print `3, 1, 2`

With this approach, your initial `hex_string` will "self document" where the letters from your array will go exactly.

Answer (score 5):

If you know the required order beforehand:

```
letters = list('1234567')
reordering = [4,2,3,1,5,4,7]
```

You can apply this to the letters:

```
new_letters = [letters[index-1] for index in reordering]
```

Output:

```
['4', '2', '3', '1', '5', '4', '7']
```

Now you can create your formatted string:

```
print(hex_string.format(*new_letters))
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the simplest approach for it to change your letters to `list('4231567')`, which allows you to mix unpacking as well as avoids the need to move around elements in the array

```
hex_string = r'''
            _____
           /     \
          /       \
    ,----(    {}    )----.
   /      \       /      \
  /   {}    \_____/   {}    \
  \        /     \        /
   \      /       \      /
    )----(    {}    )----(
   /      \       /      \
  /        \_____/        \
  \   {}    /     \   {}    /
   \      /       \      /
    `----(    {}    )----'
          \       /
           \_____/
'''

letters = list('4231547')

print(hex_string.format(*letters))
```

The output will be

```
            _____
           /     \
          /       \
    ,----(    4    )----.
   /      \       /      \
  /   2    \_____/   3    \
  \        /     \        /
   \      /       \      /
    )----(    1    )----(
   /      \       /      \
  /        \_____/        \
  \   5    /     \   6    /
   \      /       \      /
    `----(    7    )----'
          \       /
           \_____/
```

Or expanding on the idea suggested below, use `str.format` with indexes defined to unpack the original string, but assigning different items at different positions

```
hex_string = r'''
            _____
           /     \
          /       \
    ,----(    {3}    )----.
   /      \       /      \
  /   {1}    \_____/   {2}    \
  \        /     \        /
   \      /       \      /
    )----(    {0}    )----(
   /      \       /      \
  /        \_____/        \
  \   {4}    /     \   {5}    /
   \      /       \      /
    `----(    {6}    )----'
          \       /
           \_____/
'''

letters = list('1234567')

print(hex_string.format(*letters))
```

This also give you a better reference point in the sense that you know that `{0}` will contain the first item of the list, which is `1`

The output will be same as above